# Problem to set a custom image to TabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I've a image 30x30 and I want set like `TabBarItem` in my `TabBar`. But when I set the result is this:

[image]

The large blue square appears instead my image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your image file name? Becuase I had exactly same experience and it was imge file name did not match with the name I put on storyboard

Comment: Storyboard autocomplete image name with the exists

Comment: This you check this too? 

Assets.xcassets - Click on your image - Attribute Inspector - Render As - Original Image

Comment: This works!!!!!

Comment: Good to hear it works!!!! :)

Comment: How I can know the size correct to fit ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image is single-color, preferably black and white. If there's a background, even one with a low alpha, you may get this effect. The OS is trying to make an iOS-style tab bar image (think of the ones in the Music app), which is single color. It converts the non-transparent pixels to blue, and the transparent ones to white/clear. If the entire image is non-transparent, you'll end up with that.

Comment: I edited with my image, you know how transform image to single-color? Software, tool ?